# Get EditText value displayed AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get the user-input text from an EditText and display it in an AlertDialog? The Main Activity prompts the user to set an alarm, then enter a message to be displayed later once the alarm goes off. I want to be able to display whatever message the user typed in an AlertDialog.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    TimePicker picker;
    DatePicker datepicker;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public void setAlarm(View view) {
        picker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        datepicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

        Calendar AlarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBoadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 9988, intent, 0);

        AlarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.DATE, datepicker.getDayOfMonth());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datepicker.getYear());

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);

    }

}
```

**AlarmBroadCastReciever.java**

```
public class AlarmBoadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        showNotification(context);

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {

        PendingIntent contentintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, ShowDialog.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
        .setContentTitle("Reminder")
        .setContentText("Click Here To View Message");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentintent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

**ShowDialog.java**

```
public class ShowDialog extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_dialog);

        showDialog();

    }

    void showDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Message");

        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("message")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ShowDialog.this.finish();
                    closeApp();

                }
            });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
```

So when the notification is clicked on, the AlertDialog shows up, but not with the message the user entered. Ive tried getting the values and putting them in a string, but that doesnt work. Any Ideas?

Comment: you can store the text string in a shared preference

Comment: @StarsSky I tried this and it saves the string, but does not display in the AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own Dialog extending from Dialog class and add this message to constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Add the message as an EXTRA to the alarm pendingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBoadcastReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("message", yourMessageString);
```

Get the string in `AlarmBoadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method

```
yourMessageString = intent.getExtras().getString("message","No message");
```

In `showNotification` add that string as an EXTRA to `pendingintent`:

```
intent = new Intent(context, ShowDialog.class);    
intent.putExtra("message", yourMessageString);
PendingIntent contentintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

On `ShowDialog` `onCreate` method get the intent extra:

```
userMessage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("message","No message");
```

Then set that message to `AlertDialog`

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(userMessage)
```

Comment: Have you any error message? I wrote this directly in the answer box! Please edit your question and post the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question but I took the advice @StarsSky gave and used Shared Preferences to store and retrieve the message to display in the AlertDialog

**save**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(null, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("text", editText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
```

**receive**

```
SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences(null, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String text = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

Comment: You don't need to use SharedPreferences. I thing is better pass the message through intent extra. Please see my answer.

Comment: Suppose the user creates two alarms